# Solve an issue with a device that I don't have installed

Tags: windows-8.1, bluetooth

All of a sudden my Windows 8.1 Pro installation has this error message:

[image]

Problem is, **I don't have any Intel devices in my system, let alone a bluetooth adaptor**.
I first suspected that a keylogger of some kind was attached to my system, but I looked at all the ports (and even in the case, since I already had it open for a while) and there was nothing suspicious.

I also scanned my PC with Trend Micro Internet Security AND also Windows Defender, and both scans were negative, meaning that it's probably not a virus or malware lurking in my system.

Could this just be a bug with Windows, or maybe something more sinister?
What should I do to solve it, since I have not got any Intel device installed (none have ever been installed in my system)?

Comment: Check you Device Manager (Win + X > Device Manager) and open bluetooth. Can you tell us all the devices that are listed underneath, or upload a picture?

Comment: Do you have ANY bluetooth adapters attached to the system? Although it might not be Intel branded, it could be using Intel technology, which might be why the auto-installation process identifies the device as an Intel one. If you are absolutely sure you don't have any bluetooth adapters of any sort, just run through the Device Manager and unplug stuff from your PC and see if the excess device disappears, if it doesn't, then you have a virtual bluetooth device of unknown origin in your system.

Comment: @JamesLui I have no bluetooth adapters or wifi adapters, I use a LAN cable that connects to my hope-plug which connects via LAN to my router in my living room.

Comment: @NateBergeron Already checked that, there's no Intel products or anything Intel-based.

Comment: So there's absolutely *nothing* under bluetooth in the device manager?

Comment: @NateBergeron There's no 'bluetooth' section, and I've checked in the other sections and there's nothing of interest.

Comment: Did you check the system event log for further details?

Comment: @and31415 Nope. I'll check it and get back to you.